# Merge an updated repository branch, after making fork

Tags: git, merge

I did fork of an external repository . This repository had two branches : master and BRANCH1 . Then in my repository I merge Branch1 with master . After the external repository BRANCH1 updated . Now I need the updated information from the BRANCH1 in my repository . I tried
`git checkout master
git merge origin/directionOfRepository`
but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to do a git pull form the original branch into your branch.

```
 git pull origin/branch1
```

`git pull` is an alias for `git fetch + merge` so it will merge your code.